How do I allow reconnections from hosts who've forgotten my device with `bluetoothctl`?
I'm making a bluetooth stereo for my car using a Raspberry Pi. Effectively, I'm making a bluetooth speaker. I currently am able to discover and connect to the Pi using this script:
#!/bin/bash

sudo bluetoothctl <<EOF
power on
discoverable on
pairable on
agent off # For some reason, the agent needs to be turned off before reassignment?
agent NoInputNoOutput
default-agent
EOF

It's already a bit iffy with the script's output, as it seems to be sending all of the commands at the same time, causing some to be completed non-sequentially.
Another oddity is how any other agent works flawlessly through bluetoothctl, but NoInputNoOutput, the only way for me to handle connections without intervention, just can't handle reconnections after the peer forgets the pair.
I expect to be able to forget the pairing on any device and for the Pi to handle a reconnection afterwards without my phone telling me:

iPhone can no longer connect to "TacoBox". Forget this device and pair it again.


It's possible that once your iPhone is connected, you need to add a trust command in order to confirm bonding/pairing of the iPhone.The command works as follows:-
trust <iPhone's MAC address>

e.g.
trust 00:11:22:33:44:55

You will need to modify your script to capture the connected device's MAC address and then use that as the "trust" argument. First I would test this manually to make sure that it is working before modifying the script.
Another thing to try is to update /etc/bluetooth/main.conf with the following configurations:-
AlwaysPairable=true
AutoConnect=true

However, I would leave these as a later resort because they can be considered a security risk given that they configure the device to be always pairable without the user's intervention.
Finally, I would add sleep arguments in your script so that the commands are not "sent at the same time" and your script becomes more sequential.
Some relevant references:-

Cannot pair iphone on Raspberry Pi 4
AlwaysPairable in main.conf
Adding AlwaysPairable to main.conf

